# variables not being read in if statement in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to generate a form, posting to an xml doc but the code keeps taking the else option "Please make sure you filled in the fields correctly." in the registration.php file when I've supplied the variables properly.
There's 3 sections: html, javascript and php. The output I'm getting is

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <title>A Simple Example</title> 
  </head> 
  <body>
  <script src="clientSideScripts.js"></script>
  <h1>Registration Page </h1>
  <table border="0">
  <form>
   <tr>
        <td><strong>Firstname:</strong></td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" required />
        </td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Lastname:</strong></td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" required />
        </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
        <td><strong>Password:</strong></td> 
      <td>
        <input type="password" id="userPassword" name="password" required/>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
        <td><strong>Confirm Password:</strong></td> 
      <td>
        <input type="password" id="confirmPassword" name="pwdfield" required/>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr> 
        <td><strong>Email:</strong></td> 
      <td>
       <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" required pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" />
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
        <td><strong>Contact Phone:</strong></td> 
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value=""/>
      </td>
   </tr>
     <td>
        <input type="button" value="Register" onclick="registerCustomer();"/>
    </td>
  </form>
  <div id="information"/>
 </body> 
</html>


var xHRObject = false;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    xHRObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
else if (window.ActiveXObject)
    xHRObject = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

function validatePassword()
{ 
        var a = document.getElementById("userPassword"); 
        var b=document.getElementById("confirmPassword"); 
        return a.value == b.value;
}

function registerCustomer() 
{
    if(!validatePassword()) 
        alert("The passwords don't match.");
    else 
    {
        var firstname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
        var lastname = document.getElementById("lastname").value;
        var password = document.getElementById("userPassword").value;
        var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
        var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
        var url =  "registration.php?firstname=" + firstname + "&lastname" + lastname + "&password=" + password + "&email=" + email + "&phone=" + phone;
        xHRObject.open("GET", url , true);
        xHRObject.onreadystatechange = function() 
        {
            if (xHRObject.readyState == 4 && xHRObject.status == 200)
                document.getElementById('information').innerHTML = xHRObject.responseText + "<br><a href='buyonline.htm'>back</a>";
        }
        xHRObject.send(null); 
    }
}


function customerLogin() 
{
        var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
        var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
        var url =  "login.php?email=" + email + "&password=" + password;
        xHRObject.open("GET", url , true);
        xHRObject.onreadystatechange = function() 
        {
            if (xHRObject.readyState == 4 && xHRObject.status == 200)
                document.getElementById('information').innerHTML = xHRObject.responseText + "<br><a href='buyonline.htm'>back</a>";
        }
        xHRObject.send(null); 
}

<?php
if(isset($_GET["firstname"]) && isset($_GET["lastname"]) && isset($_GET["password"]) && isset($_GET["email"]))
{
    if(isEmailUnique() )
        insertCustomer();   
    else
        echo "This email is already taken, please choose another one.";
}
else echo "Please make sure you filled in the fields correctly.";

function getLastId(){
    $id = 0;
    $xmlFile = "../../data/customer.xml";
    try 
    {
        $dom = DOMDocument::load($xmlFile);
        $customers = $dom->getElementsByTagName("customer"); 

        foreach($customers as $node) 
        { 
            $cID = $node->getElementsByTagName("id");
            $cID = $cID->item(0)->nodeValue;
            if (($id < $cID )) $id = $cID;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        $doc = new DomDocument('1.0');
        $customers = $doc->createElement('customers');
        $customers = $doc->appendChild($customers);

        $doc->saveXML(); 
        return 1;
    }
    return $id;
}

function insertCustomer()
{   
    try {
        $xmlFile = "../../data/customer.xml";
        $doc = DOMDocument::load($xmlFile);
        $doc->formatOutput = true;
        $customer = $doc->createElement("customer");

        $Customers = $doc->getElementsByTagName("Customers"); 


        $customer = $Customers->item(0)->appendChild($customer);
        $newID = getLastId() + 1;
        $id = $doc->createElement('id');
        $idValue = $doc->createTextNode($newID);
        $id->appendChild($idValue);
        $customer->appendChild($id);


        $name1 = $doc->createElement('firstname');
        $nameValue = $doc->createTextNode($_GET["firstname"]);
        $value2 = $name1->appendChild($nameValue);
        $name = $customer->appendChild($name1);

        $name = $doc->createElement('lastname');
        $nameValue = $doc->createTextNode($_GET["lastname"]);
        $value2 = $name->appendChild($nameValue);
        $name = $customer->appendChild($name);

        $name = $doc->createElement('password');
        $nameValue = $doc->createTextNode($_GET["password"]);
        $value2 = $name->appendChild($nameValue);
        $name = $customer->appendChild($name);


        $name = $doc->createElement('email');
        $nameValue = $doc->createTextNode($_GET["email"]);
        $value2 = $name->appendChild($nameValue);
        $name = $customer->appendChild($name);

        $name = $doc->createElement('phone');
        $nameValue = $doc->createTextNode($_GET["phone"]);
        $value2 = $name->appendChild($nameValue);
        $name = $customer->appendChild($name);

        echo "<xmp>".$doc->save($xmlFile)."</xmp>";

    } 
    catch(Exception $e) { echo $e;} 

    echo "customer successfully registered and your new Id = ". $newID;
}


function isEmailUnique() 
{
    $xmlFile = "../../data/customer.xml";
    try 
    {
        $dom = DOMDocument::load($xmlFile);
        $customers = $dom->getElementsByTagName("customer"); 

        foreach($customers as $node) 
        { 
            $email = $node->getElementsByTagName("email");
            $email = $email->item(0)->nodeValue;

            if (($email == $_GET["email"])) return false;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        $doc = new DomDocument('1.0');
        $customers = $doc->createElement('customers');
        $customers = $doc->appendChild($customers);

        $doc->saveXML(); 
        return true;    
    }
    return true;
}
?>
```

Comment: JAVASCRIPT need to be inside `<script>...</script>` tags and should really be inside the `<head> .... </head>` tags as well

Comment: You can place multiple fields to test inside one `isset` if they are all AND tests `isset($_GET["firstname"], $_GET["lastname"], $_GET["password"], $_GET["email"])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're missing a key equals sign here (inside `registerCustomer()` function):

```
"...firstname=" + firstname + "&lastname" + lastname + "&password="
```

Contrast with:

```
"...firstname=" + firstname + "&lastname=" + lastname + "&password="
```

This means the GET index `lastname` is never being set.